# typeOrm using condition in where clause

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

```
@Injectable()
```

export class WeightPriceService {
constructor(readonly dbContext: DbContext) {}

```
async findPriceByWeight(weight: number, tariffType?: PackageMaterialType): Promise<number> {
    const { price } = await this.dbContext.tariffs.findOne({
        where: {
            type: tariffType ? tariffType : ,
            isActive: true,
            weight: { min: LessThan(weight), max: MoreThan(weight) },
        },
        relations: ['weight'],
    });


    return price;
}
```

}

Is "tariffType" parameter is true I would like to check "type:tariffType" else do not want to check "type"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for this.

```js
const obj = {
  ...(true && {my: 'obj'})
};
```

```js
const truly = 1 === 1;
const falsy = 1 !== 1;

const myObject = {
  foo: 'bar',
  ...(truly && {my: 'data'}),
  ...(falsy && {other: 'data'}),
  something: 'else'
};

console.log(myObject);
```

When the condition is `True` it will inject the object otherwise wouldn't add anything.

In your case it would be

```js
async findPriceByWeight(weight: number, tariffType?: PackageMaterialType): Promise<number> {
    const { price } = await this.dbContext.tariffs.findOne({
        where: {
            ...(tariffType && { type: tariffType }),
            isActive: true,
            weight: { min: LessThan(weight), max: MoreThan(weight) },
        },
        relations: ['weight'],
    });


    return price;
}
```